# Why does type equality fail, but type conformance succeed in this macro?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I'm trying to determine the type of a parameter passed into a macro at compile time. It seems to work when I use `<:<` but not when I use `=:=`. I'm not sure why. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've included example code below.

This macro:

```
import language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object Macros {
  def say(param: Any): Unit = macro impl

  def impl(c: Context)(param: c.Expr[Any]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    if (param.actualType.<:<(c.universe.typeOf[String])) {
      c.universe.reify { printf("string: %s\n", param.splice) }
    } else if (param.actualType.<:<(c.universe.typeOf[Int])) {
      c.universe.reify { printf("int: %d\n", param.splice) }
    } else {
      c.universe.reify { printf("any: %s\n", param.splice) }
    }
  }
}
```

Called by this code:

```
object Test extends App {
  Macros.say("Hi")
  Macros.say(1)
  Macros.say(Blah)
}

case object Blah
```

Returns:

```
string: Hi
int: 1
any: Blah
```

But if I check for type equality (`=:=`) instead the macro returns:

```
any: Hi
any: 1
any: Blah
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because type of `"Hi"` is not just `String`, it's more specific type - `String("Hi")`, which means this type contains information that it represents concrete string literal.

The same situation occurs with literal `1` - it's type is `Int(1)`, not just `Int`.

You can use `widen` method on `Type` to strip information about constant values:

```
object Macros {
  def say(param: Any): Unit = macro impl

  def impl(c: Context)(param: c.Expr[Any]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    if (param.actualType.widen.=:=(c.universe.typeOf[String])) {
      c.universe.reify { printf("string: %s\n", param.splice) }
    } else if (param.actualType.widen.=:=(c.universe.typeOf[Int])) {
      c.universe.reify { printf("int: %d\n", param.splice) }
    } else {
      c.universe.reify { printf("any: %s\n", param.splice) }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, beat me to it. It's worth noting that `Int(1)` is called a _singleton type_, i.e. a type that's only inhabited by the value `1`, and that `=:=` will work as expected with non-literal arguments (e.g. `val i = 1; Macros.say(i)`).